# function in another file wont get mocked

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have this class in a file called local.py:

```
def get_credentials(creds):
    data = creds
    return data


class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        body = "not a json"
        self.credentials = get_credentials(body)

    def run(self):
        print(self.credentials)


def main():
    inst = ClassA()
    inst.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

all it does is return the credentials passed to it.

I want to mock the `get_credentials` function for which I have another file test_local.py:

```
from local import ClassA
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

def mock_get_credentials(creds):
    return "123"

class NameTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    patch('local.get_credessntials', new=mock_get_credentials("test"))
    def test_whatever(self):
        print("true")
        inst =  ClassA()

        inst.run()
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The output I keep getting is this:

```
true
not a json
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

The fact that it spits out `"not a json"` to me shows that it is not taking in the mocked value. I don't understand why it's doing this as I feel I have follow the documentation. Would appreciate some help with this as to why its not getting mocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few typos in your code: you forgot the `@` for the patch decorator, the patched name is wrong, and you pass the function result instead of the function to `new`. Here is the relevant part of the fixed test:

```py
class NameTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('local.get_credentials', new=mock_get_credentials)
    def test_whatever(self):
        inst = ClassA()
        inst.run()
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```